# Angular material design md-tab scroll content

Tags: angularjs, material-design

This might be a simple issue, but I'm new to this...

I am trying to have an `md-tabs` element that takes the entire screen, and have only the tabs' content scroll.
Here is an example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c4hjr8op/1/)

Any ideas? thx!

Comment: I solved this with `<md-tabs md-dynamic-height>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it was a bug in 0.8.3 that is fixed now in master (commit: 74601d0)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<body ng-cloak layout="column" ng-controller="AppController as app">
    <md-toolbar layout="row" class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>
    </md-toolbar>
    <div layout="column" flex>
        <md-tabs md-stretch-tabs="always" flex>
            <md-tab label="Tab1">
                add our larger-than-life content here
            </md-tab>
            <md-tab label="Tab2">
            </md-tab>
       </md-tabs>
    </div>
</body>
```

Adding the flex attribute to md-tabs will make the content of the inner tabs (md-tab) scrollable.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this style to your `div` element inside `md-tab` :

```
div{    
  height: 100px; 
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Your container must be a fixed size.
Also, you can play with  overflow property. [**Read this**](https://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/) for more information.

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, but I want the div to take the entire height of the tab, not only X pixels...