# Scrollable content elements with Angular Material dynamic-height tabs

Tags: angularjs, scroll, tabs, angular-material

This question has come up [severa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29229300/angular-material-design-md-tab-scroll-content)l t[imes](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/4408) during the evolution of [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs), but I'm not able to make any of the suggestions work for v1.0.5. The entire page (or flex container) scrolls, moving the tabs out of view.

How can I achieve scrollable, full-height content elements?

```
<div flex>
    <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>
        <md-tab label="one">
            <md-content class="md-padding">
```

[**Demo fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/yo1kne7b/1)

Bonus Karma for incorporating [custom scrollbars](http://iominh.github.io/ng-scrollbars/).

Comment: very important comment at the end of the page https://www.bountysource.com/issues/7893048-style-tabs-md-tabs-content-is-now-flex-d

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've worked it out. By removing the `dynamic-height` directive, then using absolute positioning, it's working:

```
.tabs-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
.full-size {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

<div ng-app="sandbox">
    <div flex class="tabs-wrapper">
        <md-tabs class="full-size" md-border-bottom>
```

[**Fiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/yo1kne7b/3/)

Absolute positioning is required to [get the child of a flex element to expand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381172/css-flexbox-child-height-100).

Note: The height is incorrect in the fiddle demo. This problem doesn't occur in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the tab content inside a div and assign it a max height.

```
<md-tab label="two">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
            <div class="tab-content">
                <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab Two</h1>
            <div>
        <md-content>
<md-tab>
```

and css part

```
div.tab-content{
  max-height:350px;
}
```

[Js-fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/rpnsj75t/)

Comment: This would require a fixed height, which isn't useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
md-tabs-wrapper {
    position : fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);
}

md-tabs-content-wrapper {
    margin-top: 48px;
}
```